# populate table from value from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 view tables, the first is countries, the second states.  Individually they both work fine.  The countries table list all countries and the states table lists ALL states.

In the countries table I have a link to states passing the country_id to the states table as I only want to list states for the selected country and not ALL states.

I have tried many solutions provided by others but still cannot get it to work.  I would appreciate your help on something simple.

states.php (this is what I have so far but it is not working, the error is in the select line.)

```
<?php
$per_page = 25;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM states' SET states.country_id = countries.id FROM countries INNER JOIN countries ON states = countries WHERE states.country_id = country_id ORDER BY states.name ASC;");
$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
{
    $show_page = $_GET['page'];

    // make sure the $show_page value is valid
    if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
    {
        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
        $end = $start + $per_page; 
    }
    else
    {
        // error - show first set of results
        $start = 0;
        $end = $per_page; 
    }       
}
else
{
    // if page isn't set, show first set of results
    $start = 0;
    $end = $per_page; 
}

echo "<p><a href='state.php'>View All</a> | <b>View Page:</b> ";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{
    echo "<a href='state.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
}
echo "</p>";

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>State:</th></tr>";

for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
{
    if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'name') . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table> "; 

?>
```

Comment: What is "not working"? Does it run? Throw an error? Runs, but has wrong results? What is the desired results?

Comment: after select * from states a single quote,, why it is here?

Comment: @ cal_b - I get "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/... on line beginning ...  ($total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);)

Comment: I posted an answer however I removed it as I need to sure what you're trying to achieve. The php code looks as though you're trying to display a list of results for states in a country however the title of the question indicates you're trying to update one table with values from another. Do you have the country_id in the states table already with values matching the id's in the countries table?

Comment: @ Hamza Zafeer, sorry it should not be there, it is not in my coding.  Copied it incorrectly.  Please ignore it.  I still get error above.

Comment: @ DaveK, I have a countries table with id, and a states table with a matching country_id.  When I select states from country.php I need it to list the states for the selected country in state.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any variable containing the country selected from country.php passed to states.php so you need to figure that out first.

This is a very basic example of the query you need to pull the states based on the country "selected". But you need the $country variable specified somewhere, which you don't have in your code.

```
SELECT a.* FROM states a  
WHERE a.country_id = '".$country_id."' 
ORDER BY a.name ASC
```

If you're not using PDO (which you aren't) then you need to make sure the $country variable is safe and preferably at least escape it as well.

Comment: For this purpose, here is a simple passing of variable that I have added to top of my states.php.  <?php $_GET['country_id']; ?>

Comment: It is passing the variable but I get "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/... on line beginning ... ($total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);)

Comment: Where is your actual connection to the database?

Comment: @ DaveK - the database connection is in an include config.php file.  I have provided a stripped back version of my file.  it works fine when I select * from states.  I need it to only select states for selected country_id.  I cannot see need to Join.  When I echo the variable I get the correct value.  I would have assumed "Select * from states where country_id = 'country_id " would have done but I get nil results returned.

Comment: Ah ok you're passing a country_id to the states.php, I've modified the code above then.

The error you're getting is likely due to the query not working probably because I don't know your db structure. Depending on your host you should have an error log or you can output the mysql_error upon failure to see what's going on. You're using a deprecated function though as you should at least be using mysqli or preferably PDO (the latter requiring a significant change in how you structure your queries)

Comment: @ DaveK - Thanks for advice.  I will look into your suggestions this weekend.  This is a project I commenced and put on hold 8 yrs ago.  I better make changes now before getting deep into the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get it working how I require using the following:

```
SELECT * FROM states
WHERE country_id='.$_GET['country_id'].'
ORDER BY name ASC'
```